# Are memory-mapped files thread safe

Tags: windows, multithreading, memory, thread-safety, shared-memory

I was wondering whether you could do multithreaded writes to a single file by using [memory-mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), and making sure that two threads don't write to the same area (e.g. by interleaving fixed-size records), thus alleviating the need for synchronization at the application level, i.e. without using critical sections or mutexes in my code.

However, after googling for a bit, I'm still not sure. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) from Microsoft says:

> First, there is an obvious savings of resources because both processes
>   share both the physical page of memory and the page of hard disk
>   storage used to back the memory-mapped file. Second, there is only one
>   set of data, so all views are always coherent with one another. This
>   means that changes made to a page in the memory-mapped file via one
>   process's view are automatically reflected in a common view of the
>   memory-mapped file in another process. Essentially, Windows NT is not
>   required to do any special bookkeeping to ensure the integrity of data
>   to both applications.

But does it apply to threads belonging to the same process? It would be plausible (since my writes are disjoint), but I don't know enough about the underlying implementation of memory mapping (e.g. what book-keeping the OS does) to be sure.

Example use case, where `myFunction` is executed by each thread:

```
// crt     - index of current thread, in 0..n-1
// n       - thread count
// memArea - pointer to memory location obtained from mapping a file

void myFunction(int crt, int n, int*memArea){
    for (int i=1; i<512; i++)
        memArea[ ( sizeof(int)*( n*i + crt ) ] = n*i+crt;
}
```

If I were to run this, wait for the threads to finish, unmap the file and exit, would I end up with a file containing consecutive integers?

I would be grateful for an informed answer.

Comment: The sentence "There is only one set of data, so all views are always coherent with one another" is normative. The sentence "This means that..." is interpretive. Interpretive statements help you understand the normative text; they do not replace it. All views on a single machine are always coherent with each other, whether they are in the same process or not. But if your threads are in the same process, why create two views? Why not just share the same view between them?

Comment: I'm not opposed to sharing the view between the threads, to be honest I think that's how I would have done it. But I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: Vlad, are you aware that you can write to different parts of a file simultaneously from multiple threads using WriteFile or WriteFileEx with an asynchronous file handle?  You don't need to use memory mapping to achieve this (although memory mapping will also work).

Comment: @Harry I didn't know, but it's good to know that it's allowed.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to add the synchronization regardless if the MMF view is accessed from multiple processes or multiple threads inside one process.  Fwiw, it doesn't make any sense to use an MMF for memory sharing inside *one* process.  Threads already share the address space.

Comment: The potential use case for MMF here, assuming it were thread-safe, would be to simplify writing to a single file from multi-threaded code, by allowing the OS to deal with actually saving the data from VM to disk when appropriate.

Comment: It takes care of the writing, not threading safety.  An MMF will only be useful in this case when you don't write sequentially but write the same file section repeatedly.

Comment: Hans, surely no synchronization is required since the different threads are accessing different parts of the address space?

Comment: @Harry, it doesn't make sense to have one thread only doing writing.  Somebody ought to read or it is just a waste of time.  The read needs to be synchronized with the write.  At least that's the traditional use of shared memory.

Comment: @Hans, he's using memory mapping just as a way of writing the file.  Each thread is accessing a disjoint segment of the address space.  In this scenario, no synchronization should be necessary.

Comment: What I don't know is whether memory mapping a file in order to write to it is more or less efficient than writing the chunks of data you want into buffers and calling WriteFile[Ex] from multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

> But does it apply to threads belonging to the same process?

Yes. If one thread changes part of the data in the mapping, then all other threads immediately see that change.

You need to ensure the threads coordinate their changes so no thread is accessing an inconsistent view (eg. all access is via a critical section).

Comment: Actually, what I'd like to know is whether it's safe to do away with the critical sections - in the context of writes to non-overlapping locations.

Comment: @Vlad I'm trying to be generic here, locks are not the only way to coordinate access to avoid an inconsistent view, different threads access different parts of memory would also achieve this by having no sharing (which is the highest performance type of sharing). Note I give critical sections as an *example*.