# How is a memory mapped file synchronized with another process writing to file?

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, shared-memory

I am essentially trying to "tail" a file by using a memory mapped file within a reader process while a writer process is appending data to it (using stdio) at some time interval.

My question is how does the synchronization between the memory mapped file and the writer work behind the scenes? Would I need any additional synchronization mechanisms?

I could use inotify to find out when the file is modified but I wasn't sure if the memory mapped file is guaranteed to be updated as well.

I am using Linux ubuntu with gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are memory-mapped files thread safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035595/are-memory-mapped-files-thread-safe)

Comment: Possibly. But I'd like additional commentary on how the memory mapped file interacts with the file io and what the kernel does behind the scenes. Also note that in the other question the threads in question are both using memory mapped files. In this case only one side is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing into a memory-mapped file, the file be backed up to disk in the following cases (I assume you mapped the file with `MAP_SHARED`):

1. Using `msync` (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html)
2. When the memory page is swapped-out: the system need memory and if the memory page is a file, it will be saved to the original location.
3. When you `munmap` (see [http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html)

In either case, you should use `msync` to flush the data to disk and notify any programs watching on the file.

Comment: The writer is a process I don't have control over. I believe it is using standard file io. I'm trying to watch it using my own process. Given this would your answer still work?

Comment: What do you mean by "I believe it is using standard file io"? You can verify what kind of syscalls do the process with `strace` (watch for `write` or `msync`).

Comment: I'm not seeing either of those. It must be using memory mapped io then.

Comment: Then in this case I'm afraid you could not use `inotify`. As stated into the man page: 'The inotify API does not report file accesses and modifications that may occur because of mmap(2), msync(2), and munmap(2).'. You may use a more complex solution, trying to inject a thread into the process and catch all memory access to your memory space, but it may be hard to do and kills performance.

Comment: At some point in the future though there has to be some sync done with the hard disk. I imagine it would be under the control of the kernel IO scheduler?

Comment: Yes it should. You can play with kprobes (http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-09-11/perf-kernel-line-tracing.html). Another solution  is to reopen the file regurlarly and take care of the diff (as `tail` seems to do when `inotify` is not available).

Comment: @GHugo so without `msync`, mapped files are not synchronized till `munmap`?